# Custom Post Types Do Not work on this permalink setting https://somedominaname.com/%category%/%postname%/

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

If in Permalink settings I use this structure then on default post type this gets applied → https://somedominaname.com/%category%/%postname%/

But on Custom Post Types it is not applied effectively and on top of that the posts that were visible when this setting was applied [https://somedominaname.com/%postname%/→](https://somedominaname.com/%postname%/%E2%86%92)

https://somedominaname.com/%postname%/ also gets 404 errors.

```
 // Lingerie 
  $lingerie_labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Lingerie ', 'Post type general name', 'notables' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Lingerie ', 'Post type singular name', 'notables' ),
    'menu_name'             => _x( 'Lingerie ', 'Admin Menu text', 'notables' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Lingerie ', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'notables' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'notables' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Lingerie ', 'notables' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Lingerie ', 'notables' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Lingerie ', 'notables' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Lingerie ', 'notables' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Lingerie ', 'notables' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Lingerie ', 'notables' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Lingerie :', 'notables' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'No lingerie found.', 'notables' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No lingerie found in Trash.', 'notables' ),
    'featured_image'        => _x( 'Lingerie  Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type.', 'notables' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type.', 'notables' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type.', 'notables' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type.', 'notables' ),
    'archives'              => _x( 'Lingerie  archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus.', 'notables' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into post', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post).', 'notables' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this post', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post).', 'notables' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter lingerie list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen.', 'notables' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Lingerie  list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen.', 'notables' ),
    'items_list'            => _x( 'Lingerie  list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen.', 'notables' ),
    );
  
    $lingerie_args = array(
    'labels'             => $lingerie_labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'lingerie' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-admin-post', 
    'show_in_rest'       => true,
    'rest_base'          => 'lingerie',
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
    'add_meta_cap'       => true,
    'taxonomies'         => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    );  
    register_post_type( 'lingerie', $lingerie_args );
```

Wjat is the Mistake?

Comment: "*on default post type this gets applied*" - because that setting is indeed only for the default post type, i.e. `post`. For custom post types, the permalink structure is set using the `rewrite` arg, but if you want to use `%category%/%postname%` with your CPT, then you should use a **unique base** like `lingeries` as in `https://example.com/lingeries/category-slug/post-slug`.

Comment: Cna you convert this into an answer and show how can I do that? 404 error is coming it means it gets applied but could not direct. I could not understand what they are saying → https://wordpress.org/support/topic/category-does-not-show-in-url/

Comment: It's not applied, it's just being redirected to the correct permalink/URL. However, if you are seeing a 404 error page, then it's likely because you haven't flushed your rewrite rules (or re-save your permalinks) - which can be done by simply visiting the permalink settings page. So based on your current `rewrite` arg, try re-saving the permalinks and see whether `example.com/category-slug/lingerie-post-slug` is sending you to `example.com/lingerie/lingerie-post-slug`.

Answer (score 2):

The *Permalink structure* setting on the *Permalink Settings* admin page is only applied to the default post type, i.e. `post`. For custom post types (CPTs), you can set the permalink structure (for posts in your CPT) when registering your CPT, via the [`rewrite` argument for `register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite).

But, if you want to use `%category%/%postname%` with your CPT, then you should use a **unique base** like `lingeries` as in `https://example.com/lingeries/category-slug/post-slug/`, to avoid conflict with the default post type's permalinks.

- So for example, if the category slug is `foo-category` and the post slug is `foo-lingerie`, then the permalink would be `https://example.com/lingeries/foo-category/foo-lingerie/`.

And here's how can you achieve that:

1. Set your CPT's rewrite slug to `lingeries/%category%`, i.e. `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'lingeries/%category%' )`.
2. Use the [`post_type_link` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) to replace the `%category%` tag in the above structure with the correct post category slug.
3. Flush your rewrite rules (i.e. re-save your permalinks) by simply visiting the permalink settings page without having to click on the "Save Changes" button.

   And *remember that you need to re-save the permalinks every time you changed the rewrite slug, including after you registered/added a new post type with rewriting enabled, e.g. when simply using `'rewrite' => true`*.

Sample code for replacing the `%category%` tag (in step 2 above):

```php
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_lingerie_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
function my_lingerie_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ) {
    // Do the replacement only if the post type is lingerie.
    if ( $post && 'lingerie' === $post->post_type ) {
        // Get the categories assigned to the post.
        $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );

        // The category slug which will be used in the permalink, i.e. it replaces
        // the %category% tag.
        $category = '';

        // If there is a category assigned to the post, we use the first one.
        if ( ! empty( $categories[0] ) ) {
            $category_object = $categories[0];
            $category        = $category_object->slug;

            // If the category has one or more parents, let's add them to the
            // permalink. So for example, the permalink would look like
            // https://example.com/lingeries/parent-category/child-category/post-slug/
            // instead of https://example.com/lingeries/the-first-category/post-slug/.
            // (the-first-category refers to $categories[0])
            if ( $category_object->parent ) {
                $category = get_category_parents( $category_object->parent, false, '/', true ) . $category;
            }
        }

        // If there were no categories assigned to the post, then let's use a default
        // one. But it doesn't have to be "uncategorized", just use whatever you like..
        $category = $category ? $category : 'uncategorized';

        $post_link = str_replace( '%category%', $category, $post_link );
    }

    return $post_link;
}
```